# Text over animated javascript div

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, replit

I have an animated background that randomly displays 0s and 1s in pastel shades and fills the whole screen and Im trying to get text over that but it doesn't seem to be working. Could someone please help?
This is the html code

```
<p style="font-size:20px;z-index:-1;" class="back"></p>
<div class="main">
<p style="font-size:100px;z-index:1;">Hello!There!</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript code

```
var lines=10;
var lenght=100;
function getcolor()
{ var color='#';
    var letters = "BCDEF";
   for(var i=0;i<6;i++)
   {color+= letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];}
    return color;}
function genstring()
{var letters="01010101010101"
 var string="<p>"
 for(var i=0;i<2000;i++)
 {for(var j=0;j<Math.floor(Math.random()*10);j++)
  {
    string+=letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
  }
  string+=" "
 }
 string+="</p>"
return string;
}
function changer()
{var x=genstring()
var y=document.querySelector(".back")
var color=getcolor()
y.innerHTML=x
y.style.color=color}
setInterval("changer()",1300)
```

The complete code is on repl : https://repl.it/@Ajkallivayalil/about#script.js
And the output currently looks like this: https://about--ajkallivayalil.repl.co/.
Thank you in advance for your help ^^

Comment: I checked your code, if you add `position: absolute;` to `.back` it does indeed go behind the text.. is that what you're after?

Comment: by the way, `z-index` has no effect on staticily positioned elements (which is default, `position: static`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text ("Hello! There!") exists, it is just under field of screen (because it is in another `<div>` block, that is placed via engine under first `<div>` according default order of `<div>` on webpage). You can inspect your `div.main` element via Chrome Developer Tools or change scale of page to see where it is.

What you can do with that:

1. Add attributes `position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 40px;` to `style` of `<p style="font-size:100px;z-index:1;">Hello!There!</p>`

Then it will looks this way: 
`<p style="font-size:100px;z-index:1;position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 40px;">Hello!There!</p>`

[image]

2. Just place `div.main` over `<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">` (div with 01010101010101) in HTML code

[image]